# Functional Analysis: The rank of an operator detemines if it's a compact operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I have a problem were I have to prove the following statement:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Bannach spaces. If $A$ is a Linear Bounded operator between $A:X 
\rightarrow Y$ so that

$$Range(A)\subset Range(K)$$

with $K$ a compact operator from $X$ to $Y$ then $A$ is compact.

But I have no clue how to start and the statement Itself sounds pretty incredible anyone can give a hand?

Comment: Do you mean $Range(A) \subseteq Range(B)?$

Comment: Yes I meant the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $K$ is bounded, $\ker(K)$ is closed, so replacing $X$ by $X/\ker(K)$, we may assume that $K$ is injective. Now, $\text{Range}(A) \subset \text{Range}(K)$ implies that $C:= K^{-1}A : X\to Y$ is well-defined. We claim that it is bounded.

We appeal to the closed graph theorem: Suppose $x_n \to x$ and $Cx_n \to y$, then $Ax_n \to Ax$ and $KCx_n \to Ky$. But $KCx_n = Ax_n$, so $Ax=Ky$, whence $Cx = y$ as required.

Hence, $C$ is a bounded operator, and so $A = KC$ must be compact.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence in $X$. We need to show $(Ax_n)$ have convergent subsequence. For each $n\in \mathbb{N}, y_n:=Ax_n \in Range(A)\subseteq Range(K)$. Therefore, there exists $z_n \in X$ such that $Kz_n = y_n$. $K$ is compact, therefore $(Kz_n)$ has a convergent subsequence say $(Kz_{n_k})$. This means $(y_{n_k})=(Ax_{n_k})$ is the required convergent subsequence.

Comment: But how do you know that $z_n$ is bounded?

Comment: Yeah you suposed what we are trying to prove by saying  "$(Kzn)$ has a convergent subsequence"